# Custom ItemDataProvider with Api Platform

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I try to do a demo app with Symfony 4.3 & Api Platform

I created an entity called Event:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "put"={"denormalization_context"={"groups"={"event:update"}}},
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"event:read", "event:item:get"}}
 *          },
 *          "delete"
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"event:read"}, "swagger_definition_name"="Read"},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"event:write"}, "swagger_definition_name"="Write"},
 *     shortName="Event",
 *     attributes={
 *          "pagination_items_per_page"=10,
 *          "formats"={"jsonld", "json", "csv", "jsonhal"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Event
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"event:read", "event:item:get"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    ...
```

And an EventItemDataProvider class, my goal is to do something else before sending the entity to the response.

```
<?php

namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ItemDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\ResourceClassNotSupportedException;
use App\Entity\Event;

final class EventItemDataProvider implements ItemDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return Event::class === $resourceClass;
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?Event
    {
        // Retrieve the blog post item from somewhere then return it or null if not found
        return new Event($id);
//        return null;
    }
}
```

When it comes to Event($id) I have this error:

> Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\Entity\Event\"

What do you thing is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think is about the logic, api platform uses a restfull component. When you intercept the getItem basically you are using this route:

```html
http://example/api/event/id
```

in this part is how we need to try to figure what is happening

```
public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?Event
    {
        return new Event($id);
    }
```

in the previous code of the question, you didnt mention about the Event class has a contructor, so basically when the ApiPlatform try to extract the index or id attribute the response is null, and then the restfull structure is broken. They cannot generate the restfull url like this:

```
http://example/api/event/null ????
```

Try to set in a constructor the $id parameter for example like this:

```
class
{
     private $id;
     public function __constructor($id)
     {
         $this->id = $id;
     }
}
```

also as a comment is not mandatory return the exact Class in getItem in ApiPlatform, you can try with this:

```
public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return ['id'=> $id]
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ItemDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\ResourceClassNotSupportedException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\Event;

final class EventItemDataProvider implements ItemDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    private $repository;
    /**
     * UserDataProvider constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Event::class);
    }
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return Event::class === $resourceClass;
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?Event
    {
        // Retrieve the blog post item from somewhere then return it or null if not found
        return $this->repository->find($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a constructor to my entity don't solve the problem, now there is not the previous IRI error, but all the fields except id are null. So it still doesn't retrieve the data.

Comment: @RaKoDev Symfony has a autowire in some cases you need to enable the service, so basically you need to do, sorry, i going to modify my answer

Comment: @RaKoDev basically a DTO transform a entity or group of entities to  grouping data, in this case, you can enable a Type or Class in your Api, but without generate a table or the class been a Entity, and manually setup the Data.

Comment: Yep it's what I already did finally. I was following the example in the API Platform documentation here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/ I wonder why it's not working like in the example for me.

Answer (score 0):

add identifier

```
@ApiProperty(identifier=true)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it