# How to get custom array content with api platform itemprovider?

Tags: php, symfony, openapi, api-platform.com

I have this array which i get from somewhere:

```
array:1 [
  "content" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "accountBalanceCode" => "40000"
      "accountBalanceType" => "W"
      "accountBalanceDescription" => "Salarissen"
      "accountBalanceAmount" => "1000.00"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "accountBalanceCode" => "80000"
      "accountBalanceType" => "W"
      "accountBalanceDescription" => "Omzet"
      "accountBalanceAmount" => "-1000.00"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I also have this entity which i use as a ApiResource so api platform can recongnize is it as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\GLAccountBalanceRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  shortName="glbalance", 
 *  itemOperations ={
        "GET"
    },
   )

 */
class GLAccountBalance
{
   
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true,)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     */
    private $accountBalanceDescription;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     */
    private $accountBalanceAmount;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     */
    private $accountBalanceCode;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     */
    private $accountBalanceType;

 

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceDescription;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceDescription(?string $accountBalanceDescription): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceDescription = $accountBalanceDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceAmount;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceAmount(?float $accountBalanceAmount): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceAmount = $accountBalanceAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceCode;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceCode(?string $accountBalanceCode): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceCode = $accountBalanceCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceType;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceType(?string $accountBalanceType): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceType = $accountBalanceType;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

I want to get the array that i get from somewhere via the ApiResource so i implemented an itemdataprovider which is documented in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-item-data-provider :

```
<?php
// api/src/DataProvider/BlogPostItemDataProvider.php

namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ItemDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\BlogPost;
use App\Entity\GLAccountBalance;
use App\Http\GetYukiAccountingBalance;
use App\MethodParameters;
use Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\GLAccountScheme;

final class BalanceDataProvider implements ItemDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return GLAccountBalance::class === $resourceClass;
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?GetYukiAccountingBalance
    {
        $methodParameters = new MethodParameters();
        $administrationID = $methodParameters->administrationID;
        $sessionID = $methodParameters->sessionID;
        $transactionDate = $methodParameters->transactionDate;

        $balance = $this->yukiAccountingApiClient->GetGLAccountScheme($administrationID, $sessionID, $transactionDate);
        $content = $balance['content'];

        return $content;

    }
}
```

`$content` that i return is the array that i get from the client, which is displayed top of the post. I am a little stuck because i try to get the array directly from open api documentation but i get an error which makes sense because the array doesn't have an id:

[image]

Does anybody know a workaround for this because i am stuck and i don't know what to do.

**UPDATE**

So this question seems to look like it was already asked, but that's not the case i think. The difference is that i want to use the array as resource for ApiResource and so i am NOT using Doctrine ORM to persist the data. All i want is to show the array in open api. There doesn't seem to be a post that particular.

Comment: Hi. Shouldn'y you be using the $id parameter of the getItem() function to get the requested resource somehow?

Comment: I don't want to return the $id of the entity i just want to return the array

Comment: Yes, what i meant is that for you to return an array with data of a resource, you first need to know which resource, and you need the id to get it. If im wrong just let me know and I'll try helping with that

Comment: Do you mean the resource class GLAccount. Because i want to return the id of that but i want the data from the array in it. But i don't know how i can do that. Can you please show me?

Comment: I found a tutorial in here. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-extending/item-data-provider

public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->itemDataProvider->getItem($resourceClass, $id, $operationName, $context);
    }

Comment: I don't really understand can you show me how i can implement it for my code in a new post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom ItemDataProvider with Api Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857055/custom-itemdataprovider-with-api-platform)

Comment: Take a look at this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56881474/13013725
You basically need to inject the EntityManager in the DataProvider in order to access the repository and retrieve the data.

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the data from repository. That's why i don't use the entity manager or doctrine because i don't want to persist data in database. I just want to display the content of the array that i retrieve from a third party webservice

Comment: In the links from other posts he is using ORM to persist the data in the database i don't want to do that i just want to retrieve data from http client, convert it to ApiResource and show it in the Api platfrom user interface.

Comment: BalanceDataProvider::getItem should return a new instance of GLAccountBalance. It should set its properties with the values from $balance['content'][$id] and also set the id. 
Or you can make a CollectionDataProvider that creates a new instance for each item in $balance['content'] and returns them in an array.